# Newsstand Notification Server

Tags: iphone, push-notification, newsstand-kit, xtify

I am currently working on my first Newsstand app.  The basic gist of it is there are two XML feeds.  If no subscription is detected, it loads the free.xml which just has a couple of free issues on it.  If a subscription receipt is detected and valid, it shows the listing of all current issues.  The XML just has title, link, description, and pubDate tags in it.  The link is where it is located and the app downloads it and then displays it.  My issue is how to send out newsstand notifications.  I know it is slightly different than regular Push, in that it has ability to trigger automatic downloads of new issues.  I currently use xtify.com for standard push notifications, but I could use some guidance on how to set up notifications for the newsstand app.

Answer (score 1):

To trigger automatic downloads in the Newsstand app, you have to send an extra key-value pair as follows along with other keys. The new key content-available with value 1 is responsible for invoking the application even in the background.

{
  "aps":{
    "content-available":1,
        }
}

If your current push notifications service provider allow you to add this key, its well and good, otherwise you have to use your own server and setup push notifications and add this key to the payload.

In addition to this, make sure:
You enable Newsstand in iTunes Connect
In your Device Settings > Newsstand > Automatic Content Download must be "ON" for your app
Push notifications are "ON" for your app.

For more information on Newsstand applications, following tutorial is very helpful, please go through it. Understanding it answers many of your doubts.

http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2011/10/17/ios-newsstand-tutorial/